# how to improve Ubuntu 19.04 desktop performance on VMWare workstation?

Tags: virtualization, 19.04, vmware, iso, vmware-workstation

I installed the latest version of ubuntu desktop on my VMware workstation and it's awfully slow. In order to open firefox it takes like 10 minutes and then another while to enter a url. Can I change something in the VM settings to make it work faster? My current settings are:

- 2 GB of RAM
- 1 processor with 2 cores
- 20 GB of hard disk
- 768 MB of graphic memory

Comment: Please give more details about your setup. How much RAM did you configure for that VM?

Comment: @user228505 just updated my question with that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the amount of RAM allocated to the VM. A good place to start would be 2gb. You should also be able to allocate more video memory to the VM. Try at least 256Mb. If that does not solve the problem, try increasing the amount of CPU cores that the VM is allowed to use.

Comment: thanks a lot! I've just updated my post with my settings. please, let me know if I can improve some of them

Comment: Are you still having the same issue?

Comment: Still a bit slow. Could I edit anything to improve it more? Thank you!!

Comment: I’m at witt’s end for VMware here. You could try contacting VMware support. I don’t know how to do this or how effective it would be but maybe try turning on acceleration or switching it to KVM. I may be completely wrong here, however. Because my solution to this problem helped, would you please mark it as correct?

Comment: sure! thank you!